# Collect and view Performance Monitor information from multiple servers

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, performance-monitoring, performance-counters

I can use windows Performance Monitor to view counters like CPU, RAM, ASP.NET connections, or any other available counters, for a specific server.

Is there a tool available for windows that would collect this information from multiple servers, then send it to a central server?  Preferably with nice GUI that can easily switch between servers and have nice reports over time.

The servers may not be on same network.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at :

1. SCOM - from Microsoft - System Center Operation Management http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/system-center/datacenter-management.aspx
2. Nagios - open source - with Cacti/mrtg for graphics .

If you relay heavily on MS resources I would advice for the first option .

Comment: I looked at first option, but it seems to be pretty expensive for just a couple of servers.

Comment: Ok , then you could use Get-Event log from Power Shell http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315250.aspx, export the data into CSV and make your own charts in Excel . With a little customization you will get exactly what data you are after and statistics for each server.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommended Datadog or Dynatrace, they use new technologies like machine learning and are also able to monitor the application stack.